# ANT Deployment for SFDC

Tags: deployment, ant

Is there a way to ignore package.xml while deploying changes via ANT in Salesforce.? We only want the ANT engine to consider the folder structure mentioned within the root directory of the deploy folder and ignore the components specified in package.xml
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would want to do that? I assume you're trying to ignore some of the components, e.g. classes or pages, which you were trying to achieve by deleting unnecessary folders. What you could do is edit the package.xml in such way that you remove all <types> nodes with component types that you're trying to ignore. E.g. removing entire ApexClass <types> node from the package.xml should result in classes ("classes" folder) not being deployed.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry it is not possible to exclude the [package.xml file](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/Content/daas_package.htm), you will receive an error stating the package.xml is missing. However it is possible to use [wildcards in the definition of it](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/Content/daas_package_by_component_type.htm). This will make it easier as components in the folders are added and removed without having to keep updating the package.xml, which is i assume what your trying to achieve. This [section in the Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_types_list.htm) lists which component types support wildcards.